# Prism V2: Hosting Shell in WPF/WinForm Application

Tags: prism

I am trying to make Shell as UserControl in WPF Composite application. I Started by modifying the Quickstart app: "Quickstarts\UI Composition\ViewDiscovery". I made "UIComposition.Desktop.csproj" a UserControl class library with Shell.xaml as UserControl. Created another WPFApplication to host the Shell. Added the following code in App.xaml.cs:

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
     base.OnStartup(e);
     Bootstrapper bootStrapper = new Bootstrapper();
     bootStrapper.Run();

     // Get ShellContainer from IOC 
     IUnityContainer container = bootStrapper.Container;
     var shellElement = container.Resolve<Shell>();
     ShellContainer win = new ShellContainer();

     // Add the ShellContainer UserControl to the main window 
     win.mygrid.Children.Add(shellElement);
     win.Show();
}
```

The form shows up with the shell but when I click on the employee it doesn't show the details view. Please help!!! If any body has tried this.

Thanks & Regards,
Vishal.

Comment: The code you've posted appears to have nothing to do with clicking on employees or details views.  I don't think your problem has anything to do with making the Shell a usercontrol.  Please edit your question with the area of your application you are actually having problems with.

Comment: I used the code from quickstarts available in codeplex: "Quickstarts\UI Composition\ViewDiscovery". Just changed the Shell window to usercontrol and tried to host it in another WPF Application. 
here's the link to download the code: http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/

Comment: Perhaps you could post more of your code.  This code looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

You might try overriding the CreateShell method of the UnityBootstrapper, rather than using this OnStartup method.  I'm not 100% that this is your issue, but it's something to try.

Your OnStartup method would then be:

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
     base.OnStartup(e);
     Bootstrapper bootStrapper = new Bootstrapper();
     bootStrapper.Run();
}
```

And here is the CreateContainer method:

```
protected override DependencyObject CreateShell()
{
     var shellElement = Container.Resolve<Shell>();
     var shellContainer = new ShellContainer();

     shellContainer.mygrid.Children.Add(shellElement);
     shellContainer.Show();

     return shellContainer;

}
```

This is just a shot in the dark here.  I really don't know what the problem is, but the 100% startup method solution doesn't seem right to me.

Comment: Hi,

To reproduce the problem, modify the quickstart proj "UIComposition.Desktop.csproj" as a user control proj with shell as usercontrol and host it another WPF/winform application.
The idea here is to be able to host the shell in either WPF/WinForm Application.

Thanks & Regards,
Vishal.